# IIS : Windows authentication problem : WebSite calling an API

Tags: iis

So I work on a project where I have a Website that calls an API (both hosted on IIS), nothing special for now.
The website is configured with windows authentication allowing access to users within a group.
The API is configured with windows authentication only allowing access to the user defined as identity in the website's application pool.

I'm expecting that any user in the group calling the website would be able to see data on the website, and they won't be able to directly call the API.

However, what I get is that when calling a page of the website, the website receives a 401 error when it calls the API.

Am I missing something in the configuration ?

I hope this is clear for you.

Thank you for your upcoming help ! :)

Elyan

Comment: Can you post detailed information about 401 error? Or you can use failed request tracking to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTTP as a transport between your website and your API then you cannot restrict access to API from Postman or any other tool, including simple GET requests in browser. Any technically skilled enough user can open "Network" tab in Chrome debugger and see all requests that your site sended to the API.

So, I think you should do API request on server-side, on HTML page render step.

AS IS:
(browser or any client) -> WebSite AND (browser or any client) -> API

TO BE:
(browser or any client) -> WebSite -> API

Then you can restirct access to the API, e.g. allow request only from localhost

Comment: Thanks for you answer !
The API requests are already performed on server side actually.
Don't you think that instead of blocking the users on the API, I could try to block any request that's not coming from the website ? Is that possible on IIS ?

PS : I edited my post, It might be clearer now.

Comment: So, then you can 1. simply disable authentication on API-side (it's can be called only from localhost that is already safe). 2. extract username or other data from Windows auth data on Website-side, and send it to API as simple string or so

Comment: I.e channel "user -> website" isn't safe and need authentication, channel "website -> API" is safe if API can be called only from localhost, and no need auth